# Merge Object Properties without the Spread Operator in class

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6

I'an trying to implement the [Prototype pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) on [es6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) without the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) without success.

i want to create 10000000 stars in a canvas, so i thought this pattern would be the perfect one since by definition

> The prototype pattern is a creational design pattern in software
>   development. It is used when the type of objects to create is
>   determined by a prototypical instance, which is cloned to produce new
>   objects.

So far this is my working code with the Spread Operator:

```js
    class Prototype {// Class
            constructor(options) {// constructor 
                this.options = options;//properties
                this.context = undefined;
            }        
            //Methods 
            clone (features){ 

                let clone = new Prototype(this.options); 

                clone.options = {...clone.options, ...features};
                //Object.assign(clone.options, features);

                return clone;
            }
        } 

        //object literal    
        var options ={
            width : 200,
            height: 100
        }    
        let prototype = new Prototype(options);  

        let clone = prototype.clone({ 
            height: 800,
            color: "red"
        } ); 
        console.log("prototype:::",prototype,"clone:::",clone);
```

But using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), i get this which is not correct at all

```js
    class Prototype {// Class
            constructor(options) {// constructor 
                this.options = options;//properties
                this.context = undefined;
            }        
            //Methods 
            clone (features){ 

                let clone = new Prototype(this.options); 

                //clone.options = {...clone.options, ...features};
                Object.assign(clone.options, features);

                return clone;
            }
        } 

        //object literal    
        var options ={
            width : 200,
            height: 100
        }    
        let prototype = new Prototype(options);  

        let clone = prototype.clone({ 
            height: 800,
            color: "red"
        } ); 
        console.log("prototype:::",prototype,"clone:::",clone);
```

Comment: Using Object.assign is the best way - but use it like `clone.options = Object.assign({}, clone.options, features);` perhaps - I got that from [using babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGw9gdgpgdGAOAXAlpAzgAgLwYN4wNElgRXQBoMCYAzKAQ0QFcAnKNAXwG4g&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=stage-3%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2) (and simply using `Object.assign` instead of `_extends` that is defined in the "output" panel

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for the comment using your idea i ended up using ´ clone.options = Object.assign(clone.options, features); ´

Comment: well, that is the direct ES5 equivalent :p (according to babel)

Comment: Modifying original clone.options object is potentially wrong. `clone.options = {...clone.options, ...features}` is the right way to do that, and as it was said, it's desugared to `Object.assign({}, clone.options, features)`, not `Object.assign(clone.options, features)`.

Comment: @estus yes you are correct that was a typographical error in my previous comment.